# How to move blog title in the middle of the screen?

Tags: html, css, blogs, blogger, title

I am very new to blogging. My blog has its title description at the top-left but I want it to be in the middle of the screen and the description of the blog beneath the image.

I tried the following code but the title is still at the top-left corner:

```
<title style="text-align:center"><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<title>` element isn't used for the title displayed on your website, only for the title in the browser's top bar.

You'll have to edit the CSS file and set `#titlewrapper { text-align: center }`

Alternatively you can add `style="text-align: center"` in the `<div id='titlewrapper'>` in your HTML.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="text-align:center">Title of your blog</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I got it. The title is wrapped with a `<h1>` which is by default aligned at the left. so change it's CSS to `text-align:center;`

Use this

```
#titlewrapper h1 { text-align:center; }
```

Comment: `<h1>` is assigned a class `title` already, so just add `!important` just in case it doesnot work.

Comment: You won't need !important. If you do your CSS well you won't need it ever.

Comment: @Litso, You are right, but as this is about a blog, we might need to override in some cases.

Comment: Hmm, looking at the html of the blog I'm afraid you could be right. That source code is a horrible horrible mess.

Comment: @Litso, it is messy isn't? :D

Comment: Calling that messy is like calling the holocaust unfriendly. It's way worse than that :P

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for me
STEP1: Dashboard > Tepmlate > Edit HTML
STEP2:Search in the editor by pressing Ctrl+F for the following headercode:`.Header h1 {`
STEP3: Save your work and refresh the page
THE BLOG TITLE SHOULD NOW BE IN THE MIDDLE OF THE PAGE

BONUS
- Here is the code I added: `text-align: center;`
You can also add the same code in the description below your blog title code to align it at the center. Here is the description code you should search for in the editor: `.Header .description {`
Add the same code in it `text-align: center;`

Answer (score -1):

You can also put `style="text-align: center"` next to `div class='titlewrapper'` in html and it will work.